# Number of array elementsbof dynamic allocated array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, element

I have problems finding the number of array elements in my dynamical allocated array.
If I have a normal Array I know how to find out how much elements are in there with:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};

printf("Number of array elements: %i\n",(int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0])));
```

this prints me:

```
Number of array elements: 3
```

But when I want to dynamically allocate an array and know its size I can't get it working the same way:

int *array;

```
array = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
printf("Number of array elements: %i\n",(int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0])));
```

This always gives me:

```
Number of array elements: 2
```

No matter how much how small or big I make the allocation it always prints

```
2
```

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see different size is because the underlaying data isn't the same.

In you first example, you have statically compiled **array** of integers. This array elements are all **aligned** in memory and `array` **is** the array. Using `sizeof(array)` allows you to get the overall size of this array.

In the second example, you have a dynamically allocated pointer on an array of integers. This is totally different in memory. The `array` variable isn't the array practically speaking. It's the pointer to the first element. Using `sizeof(array)` here returns the size of the pointer on the first element, hence 8.